# How to move data from one database to another

Tags: postgresql, copy

I would like to copy data from table A database A to table b database b in postgres.

I am able to use copy to write data out to a file from table A in DB A
but when I try copy into database b table B it says "ERROR: must be super user to copy to and from file"

Please help and let me know how I should data from a flatfile into a table in a database.... the db is postgres 9.x

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html):

> COPY **naming a file** or command is only allowed to database **superusers** or users who are granted one of the default roles **pg_read_server_files, pg_write_server_files**, or pg_execute_server_program, since it allows reading or writing any file or running a program that the server has privileges to access.

However you can use [pipeline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_(Unix)) to transmit data from one database to another one without using of intermediate file(s):

```
psql -d A -c "copy a to stdout" | psql -d B -c "copy b from stdin"
```

Read more about [psql utility](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html) and its usage.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I prefer to create the output as "INSERT STATEMENTS"... this will give me maximum portability. i.e I can use the file to load any database (as we have many dbs running the same dataset..) while the GUI tool like dbeaver is created the insert statement, as a file, I would like to run it as a script.. so I can schedule it... and run non-interactively...

Comment: @Gee Hmmm... Ok, look at the `--column-inserts` option of the `pg_dump` utility: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html As mentioned: *it is mainly useful for making dumps that can be loaded into non-PostgreSQL databases.*